# Selenium, JavaScript: Extract Element CSS from Active Element

Tags: javascript, selenium

Basically, I want to be able to grab the CSS of the currently active element, so that I can pass that over to the abstraction library that we have, meaning we can use all of the functionality that we've added into our library with the active element.

We can get the active element in WebDriver form using:

```
driver.switchTo().activeElement();
```

Is there a way of getting the elements css somehow, without iterating over the numerous possibilities of tags, attributes and parent elements for whatever the active element may be? Or will I have to do a huge amount of looping in order to build up the css?

Comment: When you say CSS, do you mean the CSS selector or the CSS properties of the active element?

Comment: @GPT14 I do indeed

Comment: `driver.switchTo().activeElement();` returns an object of the type `WebElement`. Passing this `WebElement` directly to your abstraction library would be simpler than reverse engineering a CSS selector from it.

Comment: I guess I could implement a way to include a web element or a locator... That would definitely work, and would definitely mean less code than trying to reverse engineer the CSS selector.

If you post that as an answer, I'll be happy to accept and upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`driver.switchTo().activeElement();` returns an object of the type `WebElement`. Passing this `WebElement` directly to your abstraction library would be simpler than reverse engineering a CSS selector from it.